# Let $E(x) = x^4 + 2x^3+mx^2-12x+9$. Prove that for any $m \ge 5$, $E(x) \ge 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $E(x) = x^4 + 2x^3+mx^2-12x+9$. Prove that for any $m \ge 5$, $E(x) \ge 0$

Any idea is really appreciated. I don't know how to start.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd start with $x_1=x+\frac{1}{2}$ to get rid of $x^3$ and see if things get simpler [after that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28y-1%2F2%29%5E4%2B2*%28y-1%2F2%29%5E3%2Bm*%28y-1%2F2%29%5E2%E2%88%9212*%28y-1%2F2%29%2B9).

Comment: More generally, one can show that $E(x)\ge 0$ if $m\ge b$, where $b\approx .07$ is the unique positive root of the polynomial$\;t^4-5t^3+52t^2+1080t-75$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the first thing I did is to substitute $m=5+q$ so $E(x) = x^4 + 2x^3 + 5x^2 + qx^2-12x+9$ and the problem becomes $5+q>=5$ so $q>=0$ now we can reaarange some terms and we get $E(x) = (x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2) + (4x^2 - 12x + 9) + qx^2$ and now $E(x) = x^2(x+1)^2 + (2x-3)^2 + qx^2$ and if $q>=0$ than all terms are non-negative

Answer (score 4):

Because
$$E(x) = (m-5)x^2+(x-1)^2\left[(x+2)^2+\frac{24}{5}\right]+\frac{(4x+1)^2}{5}.$$
Thefore $E(x) \geqslant 0$ if $m \geqslant 5.$

Comment: How in the world did you obtain this equality?) I'm interested in the sloution process, since the result is rather obvious to verify therefore it's not that interesting.

Comment: See method here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h479486p3302291